# Execute JUnit based on Constant value

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I have this class with defined constants

```
public class Constants {
    public static final boolean TEST = true;
}
```

I would like to make a check is this constant TRUE like this:

```
@Test
@EnabledIf("'true' == Constants.TEST")
public void theMeasurementSampleScreenFromPickConfirm() throws InterruptedException {
   // some code execution
}
```

But I get error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.reflect.Method org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getRequiredMethod(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class[])'`

Do you know how I can implement this check properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use single quote as you are comparing a boolean value.

**Solution 1:** Append the value in the annotation itself.

```
@Test
@EnabledIf("#{" + Constants.TEST + "}")
public void theMeasurementSampleScreenFromPickConfirm() throws InterruptedException {
   // some code execution
}
```

**Solution 2 :** Using Spring Expression Language, you can use **Type** operator by providing the fully qualified name of the class. For example : If the `Constants` class is in the `com.example` package, then

```
@Test
@EnabledIf("#{T(com.example.Constants).TEST}")
public void theMeasurementSampleScreenFromPickConfirm() throws InterruptedException {
       // some code execution
}
```

**Note:** This will only work for Spring projects with Spring Boot Starter Test (internally uses **JUnit** by default) support as **SpEL** cannot be evaluated if it's non-spring project. **JUnit** doesn't support the evaluation of **SpEL** without Spring independently.

So, create a spring boot project with `spring-boot-starter-test` and use `@EnabledIf` annotation from `spring-boot-starter-test` which is capable of evaluating Spring Expression Language.

Comment: Both proposed solutions fail with `org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition`.

Comment: @Lesiak I have updated my answer. Now this works. You can check it.

Comment: Indeed, this one is fine

Comment: Good solution but I get `org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition [org.junit.jupiter.api.condition.EnabledIfCondition]: [#{T(org.automation.utils).TEST == true}] is not a valid fully qualified method name: it must start with a fully qualified class name followed by a '#' and then the method name, optionally followed by a parameter list enclosed in parentheses.
`

Comment: @PeterPenzov You forgot to add the class. Right one : `#{T(org.automation.utils.Constants).TEST == true}` . This will work

Comment: Again `org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition [org.junit.jupiter.api.condition.EnabledIfCondition]: [#{T(org.automation.utils.Constants).TEST == true}] is not a valid fully qualified method name: it must start with a fully qualified class name followed by a '#' and then the method name, optionally followed by a parameter list enclosed in parentheses.
`

Comment: @PeterPenzov Wait

Comment: @PeterPenzov `@EnabledIf("#{T(com.example.Constants).TEST == true}")`. This is working.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Just check properly it will work.

Comment: maybe it has to do something with variable declaration: `package org.automation.utils;

public class Constants {    
    public static final boolean TEST = true;
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228474/discussion-between-anish-b-and-peter-penzov).

Answer (score 1):

When using Spring's @EnabledIf, you can use a SpEL expresion. See [@EnabledIf With a SpEL Expression](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-enabledIf#enabledif-with-a-spel-expression)

To reference a constant, use the [T operator from SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.3/reference/html/core.html#expressions-types)

> You can use the special T operator to specify an instance of java.lang.Class (the type). Static methods are invoked by using this operator as well

Also note that your TEST constant is a boolean, not a String.

Combining the above you can use:

```
@EnabledIf("#{T(com.sandbox.Constants).TEST == true}")
```

or even

```
@EnabledIf("#{T(com.sandbox.Constants).TEST}")
```